# Show that the trivial representation of G occurs exactly once in $\pi_X$

Tags: representation-theory

I am looking at the following problem in relation to representation theory:

> Let $G$ be a finite group acting on a set $X$ (we denote this action by $(g,x) \mapsto g\cdot x$). We assume that $X$ has at least two elements. Let $\pi_X$ denote the representation attached to this action.
> Suppose the action of $G$ on $X$ is transitive, that is for every $x,y \in X$ there exist $g \in G$ such that $g \cdot x=y$. Show that the trivial representation of G occurs exactly once in $\pi_X$

I know that the trivial representation of G is meant as the unique 1-dimensional irreducible trivial representation of G so if I denote it by $\sigma$ then $\sigma (g) = 1 $ for all g in G, but I am not quite sure what it means to "show that the trivial representation of G occurs exactly once in $\pi_X$" thus I am having some difficulties to finding a way of solving it.

EDIT:
I have found out that if $\pi$ is a representation and $\sigma$ is isomorphic to a subrepresentation of $\pi$, then we say that $\sigma$ appears exactly once in $\pi$ if $\sigma \oplus \sigma$ is not isomorphic to a subrepresentation of $\pi$.

However, I am still having difficulties proving this by using the definition.

Comment: It means "there is a unique subrep of $\pi_X$ isomorphic to the trivial rep"

Comment: So I should look at a subrepresentation $\pi_X$ restricted to a subset $W \subseteq V$ and and show that it is isomorphic to the trivial representation where $g \mapsto 1$ for all g in G?

Answer (score 1):

To get a representation we first need some sort of a vector space for $G$ to act on, to do this we consider the space of formal sums $\displaystyle \sum_{x \in X} c_x e_x $ where each $c_x \in \mathbb{C}$, and $e_x$ are the basis vectors.

This space is usually denoted $\mathbb{C}[X]$, now the action of $G$ on this space is given by:

$$g \cdot \sum_{x \in X} c_x e_x = \sum_{x \in X} c_x e_{gx} =\sum_{y \in X} c_{g^{-1}y} e_y. $$

This representation is the so-called $\pi_X$ you are after.

Finally, to show the trivial rep occurs only once I would suggest using character theory, although this can be done directly too if you'd like.

Comment: How would one use character theory to do that?

Comment: I’ve found a definition which I Think makes it more clear what I am to show but I am still having some difficulties doing it

Comment: Oh sorry I had the example of $S_n$ in my head when I was writing this answer, you're right, you can't use character theory here. Let's see, you know that a subrepresentation which is isomorphic to the trivial rep is just $\mathbb{C}$-multiples of a $G$-invariant vector. So suppose some vector $\displaystyle \varphi = \sum_{x \in X} c_x e_x $ is $G$-invariant, can you deduce any restrictions on the $c_x$ using that $\pi_X(g) \cdot \varphi = \varphi$ for all $g \in G$?

Comment: No, it is not quite clear to me, unfortunately..

Comment: So we have $\displaystyle \varphi = \sum_{x \in X} c_x e_x$. We act on $\varphi$ with some $g \in G$ to get $\displaystyle g \cdot \varphi = \sum_{x \in X} c_x e_{gx} = \sum_{x \in X} c_{g^{-1}x} e_x$. Now if $\varphi$ is $g$-invariant then we must have $c_x = c_{g^{-1}x}$ for every $x \in X$. Further, this relation must hold for every $g \in G$ if $\varphi$ is to be $G$-invariant, that is, $c_x = c_{g^{-1}x}$ for all $x \in X$, $g \in G$. Now we know the action of $G$ on $X$ is transitive so what elements of $X$ are in the set $\{ g^{-1}x \;|\; g \in G \}?$

Comment: Can you conclude from this what values the $c_x$ must take in order for $\varphi$ to be $G$-invariant?

Comment: So the elements in the set must be $\lbrace y \in X : g^{-1}x=y \rbrace$ as X is transitive?  And therefore the $c_x$ must take value $c_y$?

Comment: Exactly, so as the action is transitive $\lbrace y \in X : g^{-1}x=y \rbrace$ is equal to the whole of $X$.

So we know that $c_x = c_y$ for all $x,y \in X$, so we can write our $ \displaystyle \varphi = \sum_{x \in X} c_xe_x $ as $ \displaystyle \varphi = \sum_{x \in X} c e_x = \displaystyle c\sum_{x \in X} e_x $ for some $c \in \mathbb{C}$.

Finally, we have that $\displaystyle \left\lbrace c\sum_{x \in X} e_x\; |\; c \in \mathbb{C} \right\rbrace$ is a 1-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C}[X]$ which is $G$-invariant, so this is our copy of the trivial representation.

Comment: I would finally add that by construction this is the only copy of the trivial representation, so this also answers the uniqueness part.

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining it so explicitly :-)